# How to adapt a logger.warning to an export with f.write()

Tags: python, pandas, pandapower

I have this [peace of code from a library](https://github.com/e2nIEE/pandapower/blob/dde080ba1a86bb042085852c9bcd3546e0fee6f5/pandapower/diagnostic_reports.py) that raise a warning :

```
   report_methods = {
        "missing_bus_indices": diag_report.report_missing_bus_indices,
        "disconnected_elements": diag_report.report_disconnected_elements,
        "different_voltage_levels_connected": diag_report.report_different_voltage_levels_connected,
        "impedance_values_close_to_zero": diag_report.report_impedance_values_close_to_zero,
        "nominal_voltages_dont_match": diag_report.report_nominal_voltages_dont_match,
        "invalid_values": diag_report.report_invalid_values,
        "overload": diag_report.report_overload,
        "multiple_voltage_controlling_elements_per_bus": diag_report.report_multiple_voltage_controlling_elements_per_bus,
        "wrong_switch_configuration": diag_report.report_wrong_switch_configuration,
        "no_ext_grid": diag_report.report_no_ext_grid,
        "wrong_reference_system": diag_report.report_wrong_reference_system,
        "deviation_from_std_type": diag_report.report_deviation_from_std_type,
        "numba_comparison": diag_report.report_numba_comparison,
        "parallel_switches": diag_report.report_parallel_switches
    }
    # separator between log messages
    log_message_sep = ("\n --------\n")

    logger.warning("\n\n_____________ PANDAPOWER DIAGNOSTIC TOOL _____________ \n")
    for key in report_methods:
        if (key in diag_results) :
            report_methods[key]()
            logger.warning(log_message_sep)

    logger.warning("_____________ END OF PANDAPOWER DIAGNOSTIC _____________ ")
```

Here is the kind of result I get in my python console :

```
_____________ PANDAPOWER DIAGNOSTIC TOOL _____________ 
 --------
disconnected_elements:
disonnected_section: {'buses': [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122], 'lines': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120], 'loads': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120]}
 --------
 --------
impedance_values_close_to_zero:
line 0: r_ohm <= 0.0005 or x_ohm <= 0.0001
 --------
 --------
invalid_values:
line:
line 0: 'length_km' = 0.0 (restriction: >0)
 --------
 --------
 --------
 --------
 --------
 --------
 --------
 --------
 --------
_____________ END OF PANDAPOWER DIAGNOSTIC _____________
```

I would like to write this content into a txt file with f.write
I tried :

```
    for key in report_methods:
        if (key in diag_results) :
            if not report_methods[key]() is None :
                f.write(report_methods[key]())
                f.write(log_message_sep)
```

But it seams that `f.write(report_methods[key]())` is not working properly : the txt file does not contain the information needed.

How should I proceed ?

Comment: I have just seen that inside all report_method, there is this "logger.warning"...
No idea how to do what I need easily ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need to do is add a [FileHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.FileHandler) to your logging config, which will write all log messages (including log messages written by other libraries) to a designated file (*unless* the other libraries define an alternate set of handlers for their own loggers, which is unlikely since that would be terrible practice, and doesn't look to be the case in the link you provided).

I don't know what your logging config looks like (if you set one), but here's an example:

```
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('your\\log\\path_here.txt', 'w', delay=False)
file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)    # this only allows anything up to the "info" level to be written to your file

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,               # this allows all log messages to appear in the console
    format='{asctime} {lineno:<3} {levelname} {funcName}: {message}',
    datefmt='%m/%d/%y | %I:%M:%S%p',
    style='{',
    handlers=(file_handler, logging.StreamHandler())   # this adds our FileHandler and a StreamHandler (for console logs)
)
```

Note that you can specify different logging levels for each handler. In the example, I set a global level of `DEBUG` (so almost any log message is allowed), but for the FileHandler, I limit the level to just `INFO`, but you could limit it to only `WARNING` if you wish. [Here are the available logging levels](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#levels) if you aren't familiar (each level allows every level above it).

I'm ~95% sure that this is what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. It's exactly what I need !
But I still have an issue. I created another post : If you have any suggestion, feel free to answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72584413/issue-to-write-logging-warning-into-a-log-file