# Issue to write logging.warning into a .log file

Tags: python, logging, pandapower

This question is following another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72551186/how-to-adapt-a-logger-warning-to-an-export-with-f-write) I made.

In a specific .py file, I tried the following code :

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.WARNING)
logging.debug('This message should not go to the log file')
logging.info('Neither')
logging.warning('This message should go to the log file')
logging.error('And non-ASCII stuff, too, like Øresund and Malmö')
```

It's working pretty well. : the .log file is created and the data written.

Then,I tried within my code :

```
            print('diag_results>0 for %s'%self.codification_poste)
            print('---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')

            logging.basicConfig(filename='result_test.log', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.WARNING)

            logging.debug('This message should not go to the log file')
            logging.info('So not should this')
            logging.warning('And this, should')
            logging.error('And non-ASCII stuff, too, like Øresund and Malmö')

            diag_functions = ["missing_bus_indices(net)",
                              "disconnected_elements(net)",
                              "different_voltage_levels_connected(net)",
                              "impedance_values_close_to_zero(net, min_r_ohm, min_x_ohm, min_r_pu, min_x_pu)",
                              "nominal_voltages_dont_match(net, nom_voltage_tolerance)",
                              "invalid_values(net)",
                              "overload(net, overload_scaling_factor)",
                              "wrong_switch_configuration(net)",
                              "multiple_voltage_controlling_elements_per_bus(net)",
                              "no_ext_grid(net)",
                              "wrong_reference_system(net)",
                              "deviation_from_std_type(net)",
                              "numba_comparison(net, numba_tolerance)",
                              "parallel_switches(net)"]

            overload_scaling_factor = 0.001
            min_r_ohm = 0.001
            min_x_ohm = 0.001
            min_r_pu = 1e-05
            min_x_pu = 1e-05
            nom_voltage_tolerance = 0.3
            numba_tolerance = 1e-05

            diag_params = {
                "overload_scaling_factor": overload_scaling_factor,
                "min_r_ohm": min_r_ohm,
                "min_x_ohm": min_x_ohm,
                "min_r_pu": min_r_pu,
                "min_x_pu": min_x_pu,
                "nom_voltage_tolerance": nom_voltage_tolerance,
                "numba_tolerance": numba_tolerance
            }
            compact_report = True
            diag_errors = {}

            for diag_function in diag_functions:
                try:
                    diag_result = eval(diag_function)
                    if not diag_result == None:
                        diag_results[diag_function.split("(")[0]] = diag_result
                except Exception as e:
                    diag_errors[diag_function.split("(")[0]] = e

            diag_report = pp.diagnostic_reports.DiagnosticReports(self.net, diag_results, diag_errors, diag_params, compact_report=True)

            report_methods = {
                "missing_bus_indices": diag_report.report_missing_bus_indices,
                "disconnected_elements": diag_report.report_disconnected_elements,
                "different_voltage_levels_connected": diag_report.report_different_voltage_levels_connected,
                "impedance_values_close_to_zero": diag_report.report_impedance_values_close_to_zero,
                "nominal_voltages_dont_match": diag_report.report_nominal_voltages_dont_match,
                "invalid_values": diag_report.report_invalid_values,
                "overload": diag_report.report_overload,
                "multiple_voltage_controlling_elements_per_bus": diag_report.report_multiple_voltage_controlling_elements_per_bus,
                "wrong_switch_configuration": diag_report.report_wrong_switch_configuration,
                "no_ext_grid": diag_report.report_no_ext_grid,
                "wrong_reference_system": diag_report.report_wrong_reference_system,
                "deviation_from_std_type": diag_report.report_deviation_from_std_type,
                "numba_comparison": diag_report.report_numba_comparison,
                "parallel_switches": diag_report.report_parallel_switches
            }
            # separator between log messages
            log_message_sep = ("\n --------\n")



            logging.warning("\n\n_____________ PANDAPOWER DIAGNOSTIC TOOL _____________ \n")
            for key in report_methods:
                if (key in diag_results):
                    report_methods[key]()
                    logging.warning(log_message_sep)

            logging.warning("_____________ END OF PANDAPOWER DIAGNOSTIC _____________ ")
```

The .log file is created but nothing is written. Does sb have an idea Why ?

Best regards.

"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details. blablablal kjdklj lksdjlksj dklsjlkslkjdlksjdkljs dkljsdklsjdkljskljdskldj oeiz klaj oi jqs lksqjdklqs. Then, sdlkjfklsdjf. I am wonderring why . lkjqkldsj qsdlkjqskldj qsd "

Comment: It’s pretty rude to deliberately/overtly circumvent our quality filters by adding gibberish to your post - those filters are there for a reason. Please pay attention to their feedback.

Comment: I don't really see what can I add as usefull information... If you have any suggestion, i will be happy to complete.

Comment: Does the code following your logging statements complete successfully? If you run the debugger with some breakpoints within the code, does it successfully go to each breakpoint? I see no reason why it would create the file, but not write to it

Comment: yes It does complete successfully.

Comment: Okay. I can't see the rest of your code, but it's important to note that logging.basicConfig can only be ran once. After the first execution, the logger is configured and will not change, unless you set the 'force' argument to true. Make sure you only run it once

Comment: Indeed, i ran logging.basicConfig many times. It was the source of the problem. Thanks !
If i want to run it severel times to write into diferent .log files. Can I use something similar as a "f.close" to properly finish the process ?